# php file lock while using file() method

Tags: php, file, locking

```
$f = fopen($file . '.lock', 'w');
flock($f, LOCK_SH);
$data = file($file);
flock($f, LOCK_UN);
fclose($f);
unlink($file . '.lock');
```

I saw this as one of the suggestions on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789288/does-file-lock-the-file-when-reading/4789302#4789302?newreg=c86078bbdbf24c66a923c7905035716b) on locking a file when using `file()` method to read.

file lock is obtained on $file.'.lock' while file read is done on $file using the file() method.

shouldn't file read be done on $file.lock file on which lock is obtained?

Comment: Why don't you use the solution that was provived there? It's exactly what you need.

Comment: You can try to use LOCK_EX

Comment: I understand thats a working solution, but I am trying to understand how the locking works in this case. Since lock is on $file.lock while read is done on $file. What if another script writes to $file at the same time that this script is accessing $file?

Comment: @manasjay LOCK_EX is the solution for all your problems. LOCK_EX doesn't allow if another script writes to $file at the same time that this script is accessing $file.